# Can HAML be used with Less.js?

Tags: haml, less

I realize that there's going to be big support for utilizing the HAML/Sass combo. I've done tons of reading and I get the advantages.

With that said, I really like Less.js and its take on things. Is there any reason I can't run it side by side with HAML?

Thanks, and anecdotal experience is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The major pitfalls at the time I asked this question seemed to be around the ease of having LESS precompiled vs. Sass. Good solutions exist for this now, and it's no longer a major barrier either way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would depend on what you're using, Java, Python, or PHP frameworks, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 3.1 with the new assets pipeline the less gem makes using less from Rails easy, you can even do things like blah.css.less.erb.

Or are you looking for a :less block for inline CSS like you have for javascript and css?